# Java display output in columns/rows

Tags: java, concurrency, rows

I'm trying to display the output as columns instead of what I'm currently getting and they're all over the place. I want it to look somewhat like this:

Account "Account1":

0(1) 16 16,

1(0) 12 12,

2(2) 0 0

I've tried using \t as separators and printf but cannot figure it out.
Apologies if the code is poorly formatted, I'm still fairly new to coding

I appreciate any help or tips

**Account.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Account {
private static String name;
private int balance;
int Transactions; 

private static ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>(); // array list

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Check to make sure program has been called with correct number of
    // command line arguments
    if (args.length != 3) {
        System.err.println("Error: program should take exactly three command line arguments:");
        System.err.println("\t<No. of card holders> <main acct starting bal.> <backup acct. starting bal.>");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    // And then make sure that those args are all integers
    try {
        int numCards = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        Account account = new Account("Account1", Integer.parseInt(args[1]));

        // Your code to create and manage the threads should go here.
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[numCards];
        for (int i = 0; i < numCards; i++) {
            threads[i] = new Thread(new CardHolder(i, account));
            threads[i].start();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numCards; i++) {
            threads[i].join();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("All three arguments should be integers");
        System.err.println("\t<No. of card holders> <main acct starting bal.> <backup acct. starting bal.>");
    }
    printStatement();
}

// Create an account - initalisation goes in here
public Account(String name, int bal) {
    Account.name = name;
    this.balance = bal;
}

// Deposit <balance> into the account
public synchronized void deposit(int cardholder, int balance) {
    balance = balance + balance;
    notify();
    array.add(array.size()+"("+cardholder+")"+"\t"+"\t"+balance+"\t"+ balance+"\n");
    cardholder++;
}

// Withdraw <balance> from the account
public synchronized void withdraw(int cardholder, int balance) {

    if (balance < balance) {  //
        try {
            System.err.println("Not enough money");
            wait();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    balance = balance - balance;
    array.add(array.size()+"("+cardholder+")"+"\t"+balance+"\t"+"\t"+ balance+"\n");
    cardholder++;
}


// Print out the statement of transactions
public static void printStatement() { 
    System.out.printf("%s\n", "Account \"" +  name + "\":"); // cant figure out how to arrange it into rows/columns

    System.out.println(array);
 }
}
```

**CardHolder.java**

```
public class CardHolder implements Runnable {
private int id;
private Account account;
final static int numIterations = 20;

public CardHolder(int id, Account account) {
    this.id = id;
    this.account = account;
}

/*
 * run method is what is executed when you start a Thread that
 * is initialised with an instance of this class.
 * You will need to add code to keep track of local balance (cash
 * in hand) and report this when the thread completes.
 */
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numIterations; i++) {
        // Generate a random amount from 1-10
        int amount = (int)(Math.random()*10)+1;
        // Then with 50/50 chance, either deposit or withdraw it
        if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
            account.withdraw(id, amount); 
        } else {
            account.deposit(id, amount); 
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
    System.out.println("THREAD "+ id + " finished"); 

 }
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up in your `withdraw` (and other places) method you just use the variable `balance` where you meant to use `this.balance`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that you have putted in a different way the **\t** in the deposit and withdraw methods.

In deposit you have:

```
array.add(array.size()+"("+cardholder+")"+"\t"+"\t"+balance+"\t"+ balance+"\n");
```

And in withdraw:

```
array.add(array.size()+"("+cardholder+")"+"\t"+balance+"\t"+"\t"+ balance+"\n");
```

So check once again how many \t do you want to have and be sure to put them the same way in both methods.

Few things in general. As @Kevin said in a comment above, you should use **this.balance** instead balance in some places because you will be getting wrong results.

Finally, if you want to print all the Arraylist without the commas in the new line you can use **(since Java 8)**

```
array.forEach(System.out::print);
```

array is the name of your list. Also make sure to import Arrays package to use that way.

`import java.util.Arrays;`

Of course, if you don't like this way you can use a simple for loop as well:

```
for (int i=0; i<array.size();i++){
    System.out.print(array.get(i));
}
```

Then you will have your results as columns and formatted the same way.